# How do I control the spacing above a new \paragraph?

Tags: sectioning, spacing, sections-paragraphs

I'm using LaTeX using the article type documentclass.  I haven't customized any of the LaTeX variables that determine lengths, such as `\parindent`, `\topskip` etc.

I want to control the amount of vertical spacing that appears right above a new `\paragraph`.

In particular, I want to squeeze it.

Any hints?

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to this site.  I just mean the most obvious thing, without any customizations.  Whenever I start a new "\paragraph", there's some vertical spacing between the newly created paragraph and the text above it.  How do it control the amount of spacing?

Comment: Welcome.  Help us help you. :-) Edit your question to describe what you want to do, what you tried, and what it did instead of what you wanted.  Actual code helps.  What format (plain TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, etc) you're using might also be relevant.

Comment: No question is too basic for this site, as long as it's ask clearly.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Now that your document class is known, the rest isn't too hard. The definition of `\paragraph` needs to be changed. The following code snippet (to be added to your preamble) would reproduce the original definition of `\paragraph` in the `article` class:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother
```

Change `3.25ex` to a smaller value, and the vertical spacing before a paragraph section will be reduced. (The values after `\@plus` and `\@minus` are parameters for stretching and shrinking the standard space - you may change those also, but don't need to.) The `-1em` in the following argument controls the spacing after the paragraph section -- the negative sign effects that *horizontal* space is added, i.e., `\paragraph` will produce an inline heading.

Comment: This helps a lot.  Thanks!  Btw, for future reference, where do you get the default definition of \paragraph from? Again, apologies for what must be really basic questions.

Comment: If you add `\show\paragraph` to your LaTeX file, the definition of `\paragraph` is shown in your output messages (which are saved in a logfile). (For some internal macros, you will have to look up the definition in the documentation of the source code.)

Comment: I see.  This is very good to know.

Comment: @arnab: glad you found your answer.  `\paragraph` is defined in `article.cls`, but only in terms of a more primitive macro `\@startsection` which is found in `latex.ltx`.  It takes a while before it all makes sense.

Comment: I'd add that the {-1em} parameter in the above example controls spacing after the section. Not that it's relevant to the question, but this is the only place that covers @startsection in this level of detail!

Comment: I tried this and it changed two other things about `\paragraph` that I didn't want to be changed: (1) my paragraph headings are normally in italics, this switches them to bold (I can see why that happens, but I wonder how to disable it); (2) the horizontal spacing between the heading and the text is now larger. Using @lockstep and @Marcin's comments above I was able to fix this, but the answer could be improved to be more focused on the original question.

Comment: @Roly (1) means that you're not using the default settings of the `article` class. Replacing `\bfseries` with `\itshape` in my code snippet would produce an italic paragraph heading. Regarding (2), I tried to improve my answer by incorporating Marcin's comment.

Answer (score 39):

Package [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides many tools for customizing chapter/section/paragraph/etc headings. Here is an example (which also serves as an example of minimal working example ;-) ):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% provides filler text

\titlespacing{\paragraph}{%
  0pt}{%              left margin
  0.5\baselineskip}{% space before (vertical)
  1em}%               space after (horizontal)

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{Lipsum 2} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there is no easy way (that I know) to change only the vertical spacing before, you need to specify the other parameters too, namely `0pt` for left margin and `1em` for the spacing after (got that one from guessing and checking). I made the vertical spacing `0.5\baselineskip` which mean half the height of a normal line, and looks smaller that the default spacing. Obviously, you can use `0pt` to squeeze this space completely.

Comment: @arnab, @mpg: It's even better if instead of `0.5\baselineskip` you use something with stretch and shrink, as lockstep mentioned. You can, e.g., use `0.5\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip`. This is important when you have a twosided document (option `twoside` in `article`), where TeX wants to achieve a constant text height.

Comment: @Hendrik: you're right. I tried to simplify the example, but simplifying on this point probably wasn't a good idea.

Comment: +1 for encouraging use of a distributed package to change the formatting instead of an idiosyncratic patch.

Answer (score 2):

The `titlesec` package allows changing the section margins:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
```

- The above are the default values, that you can modify as needed.
- I recommend using plus and minus for spacing to adapt to how much space is left on the page.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using a KOMA-Script template such as `scartcl`:**

You can modify section spacing by using `\DeclareSectionCommand`, e.g. the default definition for `\paragraph` is:

```latex
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
level=4,
indent=0pt,
beforeskip=3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
afterskip=-1em,
font={},
tocindent=7em,
tocnumwidth=4.1em,
counterwithin=subsubsection
]{paragraph}
```

By reducing `beforeskip`, you can change this spacing to your liking.