# Unwanted vertical space between \paragraph objects

Tags: spacing, sectioning, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\section{Related Work}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1.} This is a very nice paragraph, it contains some words.
\paragraph{Paragraph 2.} This is a very nice paragraph as well, it contains a few more words.
```

Which produced the following result:

[image]

I tried applying the solutions that people proposed for "regular" paragraph spacing, i.e., paragraphs that are just text and not `\paragraph` objects, but it didn't work. These might be different cases.

How can I eliminate, or at least shorten the vertical space between the paragraph objects?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The `\paragraph` macro is usually defined in the class file, so knowing which class you are using is relevant.

Comment: Assuming you are using a standard class [this answered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4891/82917) might be useful.

Comment: `\paragraph` is a level 4 heading designed to be used after section,subsection,subsubsection,